# Wildfly, restart server group

Tags: rest, http, wildfly

I need to restart a server group, using the HTTP API. I can't figure out what the correct syntax is.

I tried a lot of

```
HashMap<String, Object> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
requestMap.put("operation", "something-something");
requestMap.put("address", "something-something");

final Response response = managementContext
    .request()
    .header("X-Requested-By", WildflyUtils.class.getName())
    .post(Entity.json(requestMap));
```

or "by hand":

```
{"operation":"something-something", "address":"something-something",  "json.pretty":1}
```

I'm guessing around. Does someone know which command is best and what the correct syntax for the address is, or where a useful documentation for the HTTP API is? The official documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API) is somewhat small.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [WildFly 11.0 Model Reference](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/11.0/index.html), but I am afraid this does not cover the domain mode.

I had a small demo code [here](https://github.com/wfdemo/jaxrs-client-demo). In your case you should do:

```
requestMap.put("address", "[\"server-group",\"myServerGroup\"]");
requestMap.put("operation", "restart-servers");
requestMap.put("blocking", "true/false");
requestMap.put("start-mode", "normal/suspend");
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether it help but I tried with the curl:

```
curl --digest -u "username:password" 'http://localhost:9990/management' --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"operation":"restart-servers","address":[{"server-group":"your_server_group"}]}'
```

for standalone:

```
curl --digest -u "username:password" 'http://localhost:9990/management' --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"operation":"reload","address":[]}'
```